# how to make @ConfigurationProperties not to be a spring bean when yml prefix is empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

how to make @ConfigurationProperties not to be a spring bean when yml prefix is empty

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "nebula")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConnectProperties {

}
```

I annotated the configuration in spring's YML configuration file

```yaml
#nebula:
#  url: 127.0.0.1:9669
#  username: root
#  password: nebula
```

but i still get a bean for `ConnectProperties`(Only the attribute of this bean is empty)

i want spring not ioc this bean when the yml's attribute empty

What can I do, thanks

Comment: What’s the problem with the bean been created?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [@ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "nebula")
```